# Nifi - Upgrading from 1.12.1 to 1.20.0 clears passwords and variables

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm performing a Nifi upgrade for the first time, upgrading from 1.12.1 to 1.20.0 on a single instance, on the same server.

I've tried a couple of different approaches, but I'm running into the scenario where the passwords and variables get cleared.

I extracted the 1.20.0 zip. I've tried two different approaches. After updating the nifi.properties and bootstrap.conf appropriately, I tried the following:

1. Copied the flow.xml.gz from 1.12.1/conf to 1.20.0/conf
2. Exported a template from 1.12 and then imported into 1.20.

I'm trying to move the state-management and database repository to external locations on the server, so I copied both the state-management and database-repository contents to the new path prior to starting 1.20.0.

In both scenarios, the passwords and variables get cleared. Are there any steps that I'm missing? Is there a way to preserve these values?

Thanks!